# How to evaluate statistical significance of two feature-based representations using the same classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistical-significance

I am new to statistical significance tests.

I have two feature-based representations learned by different machine learning models.

I compared these two representations using the same classification task and the same classifier.
To explain: I have 10000 movies and for each one of the I have two representation. I train svm on each representations to predict the genre of the movies, and I obtained f1 score and accuracy.

Now my question is how to prove that the results are statistically significant.